# Laymen's description of Laplace Smoothing

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

I have understood that Laplace Smoothing will provide a small non-zero value to the probability score. But still, I am missing something. Please if anyone can provide a better description, it will be a great help.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Well, what do you think you are missing? You know what laplace smoothing **is**, that's a start. Is it unclear to you **why** it is used? If not, can you try to describe what exactly you want to know about?